# Xamarin Forms - Acr.UserDialogs and Rg.Plugins.Popup - Toasts not showing on top of popup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently using both Acr.UserDialogs and Rg.Plugins.Popup in my Xamarin Forms project, and I'm making use of the toasts in Acr.UserDialogs extensively. However, I'm finding that toasts are not being displayed if the user is currently in a popup (from Rg.Plugins.Popup). I think that the toast is showing 'underneath' the popup.

Is there a way to set the 'z index' (I'm from a web background) in some way?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a sample which  so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm currently just in the same situation.

Comment: @Chris, Have you find any solution for this issue. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have both at the same time but what you can do is have them pop up in sequence.

just make sure you call the popall before calling PopupNavigation

```
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
```

then

```
await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Hello World", "OK");
```